# The Difference of Armadillo compilation between -larmadillo and -lopenblas -llapack

Tags: c++, compilation, armadillo

For the code below: test.cpp

when I compile it with

```
g++ -std=c++11 -I ~/armadillo-openblas/include/ -L ~/armadillo-openblas/lib/ test.cpp  -o test  -O2 -larmadillo
```

I got an error:

> ./test: error while loading shared libraries: libarmadillo.so.9:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

But I am sure libarmadillo.so.9 is under ~/armadillo-openblas/lib/.

I also tried with this:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -I ~/armadillo-openblas/include/ -L ~/armadillo-openblas/lib/ test.cpp -o test -DARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER  -lopenblas -llapack
```

It works. I know when adding `ARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER`, we can compile it this way. but how the `-larmadillo` way does not work if without `ARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER`?

By the way, what does `-O2` mean?

```
//test.cpp    
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

int main(){
  arma::arma_rng::set_seed_random();
  arma::Mat<double> A = arma::randu(4,4);
  std::cout << A << std::endl;
  return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first case should work if you remove the `-I ~/armadillo-openblas/include/ -L ~/armadillo-openblas/lib/` part. It is sufficient to use only `-larmadillo`. Armadillo is probably built with the "vanilla" BLAS and Lapack and when you specify the openBlas library it will be confused. If you want to use other libraries you have to use the `-DARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER` and specify the dependencies just as you showed.

The `-O2` flag is an optimization level for the compiler, there are a number of levels ranging from `-O0` no optimization to `-O3` and also some other e.g `-Ofast`

Comment: Hi, Claes. Thank you for your answer. The path of -I ~/armadillo-openblas is actually where armadillo installed. So what I do is to specify where the armadillo head file and library are. What surprises me is that it linked the armadillo.so.9 rather than armadillo.so to the program. I am wondering what is the difference between them?